# Is it possible create paypal business account create in india?

Tags: payment-gateway, paypal-express, internationalization

I want to create paypal business account from india for my usa business(Actually my store in usa, i want to create payment gateway using paypal). Is it possible indian contact number accept (Airtel)?

> Note : I am getting error at enter the contact number(indian number),
>   i added but still not getting massage or call.

[image]

Comment: Sorry to ask this but do you use +91 dialing code in front of your number?

Comment: No, i won't.....

Comment: So please digit your phone number with India dialing code +91.

Comment: +91 or 91 don't accept by Paypal

Comment: If you create an USA Paypal account you need an US Phone number.

Comment: Just i spoke with pay pal, they said, if you create paypal payment gateway for USA, USA country registered mobile number only allowed, and also they said if you want to enter indian mobile number you should create paypal payment gateway for india then use it as a usa payment received for the country usa, in this method they consuming currency conversion charge.  My doubt is only based on, if i use indian paypal payment gateway for receiving usa currency they applied currency conversion charge, is free for use usa paypal payment gateway.